# Python - Implementing a Future object

Tags: python, concurrency, future, concurrent.futures

I need a Future object in python3.

Python has two built in implementation:

1. asyncio module has one, but its not suitable for my application.
2. concurrent.futures has one, but its documentation state that this object should be created only by Executor objects:

> The following Future methods are meant for use in unit tests and Executor implementations.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects

The basic interface is:

```
class Future:
   def get(self):
       pass
   def set(self, val):
       pass
```

While the key here is that if `get` is called before `set`, the method blocks until value is set.

`set` is setting the value and releasing any thread that is waiting on `get`.

Is it safe to use one of the built-in implementation above in a multithreaded application?

How to implement that efficiently?

Comment: Please be more specific, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the guidance of @SolomonSlow i implemented this code:

```
from threading import Lock, Condition

class Future:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__condition = Condition(Lock())
        self.__val = None
        self.__is_set = False

    def get(self):
        with self.__condition:
            while not self.__is_set:
                self.__condition.wait()
            return self.__val

    def set(self, val):
        with self.__condition:
            if self.__is_set:
                raise RuntimeError("Future has already been set")
            self.__val = val
            self.__is_set = True
            self.__condition.notify_all()

    def done(self):
        return self.__is_set
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: could you add one example how it can be composed and run concurrently?

With GIL, is using `threading` here effective for concurrency if the job is bounded by I/O ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement that efficiently?

I don't know about efficiently, but *simply*:

Sounds like a class with a `value` member, an `is_set` member, and a `lock` and a `condition`. The `set()` method should

- lock the `lock`
- raise an error if `is_set` already is true, or else

  - `is_set = True`
  - set the value
  - `condition.notifyAll()`

The `get()` method should lock the lock and then loop waiting on the condition variable until `is_set` is True, and finally, return the value.

If there's a more efficient way to do it with pure Python code, that's beyond my ken.